# Return object where each key is an element of enum array

Tags: typescript

I am currently building a function that takes an array of enum members and returns an object where each array element is a key and the value is a string array, containing the possible options for the corresponding dropdown (in the example where I have `enum Seasons` this might for example return all the holidays in that season).

For now I am typing the result as `Partial<Record<Seasons, string[]>>` which works but is cumbersome since I already know which keys the return type is supposed to have:
All the elements of the function argument.

Is there a more elegant solution for this problem where the keys are strictly typed?
I suppose one would have to use generics but I don't have a clue how.

```
// dummy implementation
async function getGroupFromDb(group: Seasons): Promise<string[]> {
  return [];
}

enum Seasons {
  Spring = 1001,
  Summer = 1002,
  Fall = 1003,
  Winter = 1004,
}

export async function getGroupOptions(groups: Seasons[]): Promise<Partial<Record<Seasons, string[]>>>{
  const result: Partial<Record<Seasons, string[]>> = {};

  for(const group of groups){
    // find options in database
    result[group] = await getGroupFromDb(group);
  }

  return result;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBMFcFtoT1AS2gBwDYFNoYHYBcBDPRAexwFgAoAgZzhwGNQAzSR4s0AcwzwHEATiUgoAYkOgARAEYAKLkJEAuUAGUMtMjQCUKgAoTENDAB4aeAYhxcA2gF0AfKADeVUKAG9IAnKHsBuKgBfKipcGDUNGi0XNzUUS2tQAF5QAEYABgy0gBo41RhsART0rIAmPMp3UQI0NBLMjIBmSvcAdSs8DGLUxoAWSpDKMIAPFBIBPFBaeiZWdlJfHn5FFAB5FA4cGnlVmhV1TW37XVADEmgjUz0CScRakwAlDAYJ8BND6O2c0HNE20cDgcriqoFe2ymnhokDQeH0t2ID2erwE70+Wh+fysAKBJWcQUCw1BzAmsnB5m4q1AJGYlOEKB0IPc7hALCs4Gpm0WNCQvnARAI0loGDi7ihMLwNgU9LsJQIAHcCIgpstBPTxBcZLt6dpCe4hnFPHhvL5xbDCUEgA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
export async function getGroupOptions<
  T extends Seasons[]
>(groups: T): Promise<Record<T[number], string[]>> {
  const result: Partial<Record<Seasons, string[]>> = {};

  for(const group of groups){
    // find options in database
    result[group] = await getGroupFromDb(group);
  }

  return result as Promise<Record<T[number], string[]>>;
}
```

We can store the elements passed as `groups` in the generic type `T`. The return type of the function would be a `Record` where the keys are `T[number]`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBMFcFtoT1AS2gBwDYFNoYHYBcBDPRAexwFgAoAgZzhwGNQAzSR4s0AcwzwHEATiUgoAYkOgARAEYAKLkJEAuUAGUMtMjQCUKgAoTENDAB4aeAYhxcA2gF0AfKADeVUKAG9IAnKHsBuKgBfKipcGDUNGi0XNzUUS2tQAF5QAEYABgy0gBo41RhsART0rIAmPMp3UQI0NBLMjIBmSvcAdSs8DGLUxoAWSpDKMIAPFBIBPFBaeiZWdlJfHn5FFAB5FA4cGhMAFVAMEa6ccBpIzW37B3lVmhVd3VADEmgjUwAlDAYJ8D2bHBg0m6dhyoHMiVsjgcriqoG%202ymnhokDQeH0BEmiFqJk%203wEv3UFxooPBVkhDicqWcQUCw1hzAmsnh5m4q1AJGYrOEKB0MPc7hALCs4HZm0WZysECIBGktAwcXcSJReBsCm5dhKBAA7gREFNloJueIXjIbtztLT3EM4p48N5fErUdMzs9XsYcV8fn8AdAgQIQWCLGSrg5adbKMypgQSgbVhstjRZDZCdFtgA6VQJMmglNaNMdfDA7RUQX8gB6AH4gA)

Comment: So the `T[number]` means "any element of T", correct?

Comment: Yes, it generates a union of all elements of `T`